# How to use namespace in WordPress Plugin with classes

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, namespaces

I am developing a wordpress plugin using OOPS concept with classes.
I want to use namespace in them.
Does anyone has any idea how to implement that in my plugin ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please define namespace with first line and use like we do it below.

```
    <?php 
    namespace Appsense\popop;
    class shortcode{
        public function gernerateShortcode(){
            add_shortcode('appsense_popop',array('Appsense\popop\shortcode','popop_shortcode'));
        }
        public function popop_shortcode(){
          $output = "Hello world!";
          return $output;
        }
    }
```